# What is equivalent to findViewById using LayoutInflater in Android?

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I don't fully understand LayoutInflater functions though I used it in my projects. For me it's just a way to find view when I cannot call **findViewById** method. But sometimes it does not work like I expect.

I have this really simple layout (main.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:id="@+id/layout">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World, MyActivity"
            android:id="@+id/txt"/>

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Change text"
            android:id="@+id/btn"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

What I want is very simple - just to change text inside TextView when pressing the button. Everything works fine like this

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
        double random = Math.random();
        txt.setText(String.valueOf(random));
    }
}
```

But I want to understand what would be the equivalent using **LayoutInflater**? I tried this, but without success, TextView didn't change its value

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View main = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
    TextView txt = (TextView) main.findViewById(R.id.txt);
    double random = Math.random();
    txt.setText(String.valueOf(random));
}
```

But when debugging I can see that each variable populates with right value. I mean **txt** variable actually contains TextView which value is "Hello World, MyActivity", and after **setText** method it contains some random number but I couldn't see this changes on UI. It's the main problem I faced with LayoutInflater in my projects - for some reason I can't update inflated views. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For me it's just a way to find view when I cannot call findViewById
>   method.

That is incorrect. The `LayoutInflater` is used to inflate(build) a view hierarchy from the provided xml layout file. With your second code snippet you build the view hierarchy from the layout file(`R.layout.main`), find the `TextView` from that inflated view and set the text on it. The problem is that this inflated view isn't attached to the visibile UI of the `Activity`. You could see the changes, for example, if you call again `setContentView` this time giving it the inflated view. This will make the content of your `Activity` to be the newly inflated `View`:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View main = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
TextView txt = (TextView) main.findViewById(R.id.txt);
double random = Math.random();
txt.setText(String.valueOf(random));
setContentView(main);
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I know that I'm wrong that's why I'm asking this question. So, is it impossible to update view with LayoutInflater without using setContentView method?

Comment: @VitaliiKorsakov Yes, it's impossible. The `LayoutInflater` will create new views with the `inflate` method, so you don't have a "connections"(or reference if you prefer) to old views that are already present in the layout of the `Activity`.